# When I do a 2D array randomized images, there are duplicates, how can i make it unique?

Tags: java, javafx

I didn't want to post my full code as its big, but basically this is part of a function that randomizes the 2D array of images, the only problem is here are many duplicates of the same image, where I want to have for each row and column a unique picture. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
  Random r= new Random();
    int rand1, rand2;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        rand1= rand.nextInt((3 - 0) + 1) + 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            rand2= rand.nextInt((3 - 0) + 1) + 0;
            Button b = new Button();
            b.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(images+ rand1+ rand2+ ".png"))));
            grid[r][c] = b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using a 2d array, try using a Set (like HashSet). This makes it so that all items within the object are unique. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a HashSet and what I'm trying to do is I have about 40 images, named as follows, "image01.png" , "image02.png" and so on and so fourth, but trying to import each image randomly for the grid[R][C] order

Comment: Forget about images, your problem is a simple one: how do you compose all possible combinations of indexes, and randomize the order, from which you can draw next value.

Comment: Put the images (or just their names) in a list and call [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

Comment: So there is no other way around it? maybe using an if statement or anything? I dont like to use something I don't know how to use

Comment: @markdevan Why don't you just learn how to use it? Then you won't be using something you don't know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to draw all unique combinations in a random order, adopt that for your file names:

```
@Test
public void combinations() {
    int[] prefixes = new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int[] suffixes = new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    List<String> literals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int prefix: prefixes) {
        for (int suffix: suffixes) {
            literals.add("" + prefix + suffix);
        }
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    while (!literals.isEmpty()) {
        String literal = literals.remove(random.nextInt(literals.size()));
        System.out.println(literal);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
23
04
25
35
43
41
05
20
45
31
11
01
10
34
14
12
22
44
30
33
02
03
24
15
00
32
42
13
21
40
```

As suggested elsewhere you can also just run `Collections.shuffle(literals)` and then iterate through the list in order:

```
Collections.shuffle(literals);

for (String literal: literals) {
    System.out.println(literal);
}
```

```
05
33
35
25
31
14
22
23
45
40
32
15
02
04
30
12
00
11
44
24
42
13
41
21
20
10
03
34
01
43
```

Comment: and how do u specify the range ? Like which does from 0 to 40, just to make sure I understand your solution.

Comment: Look, you are trying to solve a non-trivial, even if a simple, problem. Why would not you start with learning the basics of the language? The code above could hardly be simpler, even if you do not know Java just reading it as English.

Comment: thank you! I just need to know every little thing that I'm doing with programming.

Comment: @OlegSklyar Would you rather add 2 whitespaces or `<br>` to the end of each line to preserve the line breaks? Note this would result in non-monospaced font being used...

Comment: @fabian I would leave as it was in one line, it was there for indication purposes not for programmatically correctness (or I would change println to print(literal + " ") and leave the output)